# Trouble using Provider

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-provider

I've been trying trying to make the checkout show the total price of what's in the basket. But turns it's way more difficult than I thought.

The list `userOrders` holds all the user has put into the basket

https://ibb.co/DQwTyHC

Provider class: (Or what it's suppossed to be)

```
class TotalPrice with ChangeNotifier {
  int ordersTotalPrice = 0;

  int totalPrice() {
    final ordersTotalPrice =
        userOrders.fold(0, (sum, order) => sum + order.totalPrice);
    notifyListeners();
    return ordersTotalPrice;
  }
}
```

Food:

```
class Food {
  String imgUrl;
  String desc;
  String name;
  String waitTime;
  num score;
  int price;
  int quantity;
  List<Map<String, String>> ingredients;
  String about;
  bool highlight;
  Food(this.imgUrl, this.desc, this.name, this.waitTime, this.score, this.price,
      this.quantity, this.ingredients, this.about,
      {this.highlight = false});
}
```

CheckOut button

```
class _NextButtonState extends State<NextButton> {
  String getCurrency() {
    var format = NumberFormat.simpleCurrency(name: 'NGN');
    return format.currencySymbol;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return userOrders.isNotEmpty
        ? Container(
            color: Colors.transparent,
            padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10.0, 10.0, 5.0, 5.0),
            height: 60,
            width: double.infinity,
            child: ElevatedButton(
              style: ButtonStyle(
                shape: MaterialStateProperty.all<RoundedRectangleBorder>(
                  RoundedRectangleBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(18.0),
                    side: const BorderSide(color: Colors.transparent),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              child: Text(
                '${getCurrency()}${context.watch<TotalPrice>().ordersTotalPrice}',
                style: const TextStyle(
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  fontSize: 18.0,
                ),
              ),
              onPressed: () {},
            ),
          )
        : Text('');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here, you introduced local variable so the field `orderTotalPrice` didn't get updated as you have

```
final ordersTotalPrice = userOrders.fold(0, (sum, order) => sum + order.totalPrice);
```

change this line as following

```
ordersTotalPrice = userOrders.fold(0, (sum, order) => sum + order.totalPrice);
```

**Edited**

Use `AnimationBuilder` to refresh the changed data in UI.

```
AnimatedBuilder(
            animation: context.read<TotalPrice>(),
           
            builder: (BuildContext context, Widget? child) {
              return Text('${context.read<TotalPrice>().ordersTotalPrice}');
            },
          )
```

Comment: It still doesn't work

Comment: I edited the answer, wrap `Text` with `AnimatedBuilder`

Comment: I appreciate your help a lot but it still shows 0 no matter what I do

Comment: Make sure you called `totalPrice()` function before render the UI and after price value got changed

Comment: Thanks so much! It works now. Although the price doesn't update when I remove something from the list

Comment: From what I can see I think it only gets the value once and after that it never updates no matter what I do. Funny, considering that's the whole reason I'm using Provider. I solved this  by creating an update Provider function that updates the cart's total price and calling it whenever the user enters the Cart page. Is this the ideal solution or is there a better way for it to be done

Comment: I suggest you to manage cart details in one provider, which has list of `items(products)` with quantity and `totalPrice`, the provider should have methods `add`, `remove`, `updatePrice`. `add` and `remove` will be call while adding and removing which calls `updatePrice` internally. `updatePrice` will have calculation of `totalPrice`, and this has to be called from `add` and `remove` or where you really want to refresh the total.

Comment: If you don't mind I have a new question. Hoping you can help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75461107/trying-to-modify-a-specific-property-of-an-object-from-a-list-of-that-object